# How to turn a Hashmap<String, String> to a JSONPObject

Tags: java

I want to turn a `HashMap<String, String>`  into a `JSONPOject`, please, before downvote the question note the difference between `JSONPOject` and `JSONObject`. I have already tried like new `JSONPObject({HasMap<String, String>})`, but it doesn´t work, throws an error that says "Array initializer is not allowed here", how can I do it? Here my code, please ignore the declarations on spanish ;).

Code

```
public JSONPObject getOnlyDistritosTarificacion(String string) {

        List<Map<String, Object>> filas_distritos = null;
        HashMap<String, String> distrito = new HashMap<>();

        filas_distritos = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(CONSULTA_SOLO_DISTRITOS, new Object[]{string, string});

        if ((filas_distritos != null) && (!filas_distritos.isEmpty()) || (filas_distritos.size() != 0)) {
            Map<String, Object> row = filas_distritos.get(0);
            distrito.put("distrito", (String) row.get("DISTRITO"));
            distrito.put("inicio", (String) row.get("INICIO"));
            distrito.put("fin", (String) row.get("FIN"));
            distrito.put("mensaje", "El n&uacute;mero consultado (" + string + ") ya pertenece a un Distrito de Tarificaci&oacute;n.");


            JSONPObject jsonpObject = new JSONPObject({distrito});
        }else {
            distrito.put("mensaje", "El n&uacute;mero consultado (" + string + ") no pertenece a un Distrito de Tarificaci&oacute;n.");
        }
        return distrito;
    }
```

Comment: What `JSONPObject`? The one from the Jackson library? If so, why are you trying to pass an array initializer to the constructor?

Comment: off topic just for future reference, always use english in your codes variables methods etc. good for you and whoever else might try to read your code :)

Comment: spanglish rules in code! :)

Comment: guys I know that we must always code on english, but this is inherited code , thats why I told u to ignore the spanish, also , I dont know why I cant use the JSONObject declaration and only allows to use the JSONPObject

Comment: I repeat my question: "What `JSONPObject`? There is no `JSONPObject` in the Java standard libraries, so which one are you using?"

Comment: The one of Jackson as you said , the one of XML

Comment: `new JSONPObject("yourJSONPFunctionName", distrito);`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks a lot !